# What is Local Connection in Expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

It seems that there are three ways to run an expo app: `Tunnel`, `LAN`, and `Local` connection.

When is Local connection used and how to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Local can be used when you only want to test the app on an emulator. As soon as you want to test your app on a real device you have to select LAN (or Tunnel).